# Представление числа 2 в n степени (например: 8 – 2^3, 32 – 2^5)

Tags: c, файлы

> Текстовый файл содержит целые числа. Заменить все числа, представляющие число два в целочисленной степени сочетанием 2^n (где n – степень). Например: 8 – 2^3, 32 – 2^5

Подскажите алгоритм решения подобных задач.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Берете число, проверяете, а не 2 ли это в степени `n`, если да - заменяете...

Ну, а проверить, является ли `x` степенью 2, очень просто - вычислить `x&(x-1)` - для степени 2 это будет нуль... (правда, нужно еще проверить, что `x` само не является нулем).

Степень-то вычислить особых проблем не составит?

Comment: что такое &? степень числа не знаю как вычислить

Comment: `&` - оператор языка C. Степень... Ну, например, посчитайте, сколько раз нужно выполнить деление числа на 2, чтобы получить нуль :)  Еще раз - у вас в вопросе *Подскажите алгоритм решения подобных задач*. Он подсказан.

Comment: да, спасибо, просто мне нужно огромное количество задач перерешать за максимально короткий срок, голова уже кипит, очевидных вещей не вижу

Comment: еще вопрос, как проверить является ли х степенью 3?

Comment: Тут такого простого варианта я не знаю. Навскидку - в цикле проверял бы остаток от деления на 3, если не нулевой - не степень, если нулевой - делим на 3, и так пока не получим 1...

Comment: Функция `ffs()/fls()` или `ctz()/clz()` даст сразу ответ про степень двойки.

Comment: @0andriy Не припоминаю таких в стандарте языка :)

Comment: Степени 3 таблично можно проверять (решение *в лоб*), там-то чисел совсем немного.

Comment: @0andriy Так и степеней двойки тоже немного - обычно не больше 64 :)

Comment: Это интринсики во многих компиляторах сейчас (т.к. реально в современных процессорах это просто одна инструкция) либо библиотечные.

Comment: @0andriy Как только вы мне покажете описание этой функции в стандарте C, так сразу извинюсь и исправлю свой ответ...

Comment: Где-то было указание не использовать возможности компилятора? И я вас не прошу извиняться (не за что), просто мы раширяем кругозор, правда?

Comment: Да нет, это вы расширяете, а я так, просто покурить вышел... Надеюсь, я последний раз ответил на ваш комментарий, и у меня хватит выдержки просто не обращать внимания на то, что вы тут несе... в смысле, пишете.